# Probability that two tickets drawn out of $n$ tickets with and without replacement and are consecutive integers

Tags: probability, solution-verification

I have a question given as follows:

> A box contains $n$ tickets numbered $1$ to $n$. Two tickets are chosen at random. Find the probability that the numbers will be consecutive integers, if the tickets are chosen (i)
> without replacement, and (ii) with replacement.

**MY ATTEMPT**

The ways in which consecutive integers can be drawn are as follows:
$$(1,2), (2,3), \dots , (n - 1, n)$$
$$(2,1), (3,2), \dots , (n, n - 1)$$

So number of favourable cases = $2(n - 1)$.

i) Total number of cases = $n(n - 1)$ (since without replacement).
So probability $$= \frac{2(n-1)}{n(n-1)} = \frac{2}{n}$$

ii) Total number of cases = $n^2$ (since with replacement).
So probability $$= \frac{2(n-1)}{n^2}$$

Is my attempt is correct? Any kind of help will be highly grateful. Thanking in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your thought is correct, there is only a problem in your first formula for $n=1$. In that case, the probability should be $0$, not $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your method and answer are correct. As a sanity check, analyze the experiment for $n=2$.

In first case, one is sure to draw consecutive integers. Does your result give $1$?

In second case, the second card can be same as first or consecutive to it. These two are only possibilities. Does your result evaluate to $1/2$?